# How do I set the default value for a checkboxes element?

Tags: views, forms

I'm trying to set the default for a checkboxes element in `hook_form_alter()`.

```php
$form['average'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => array('a','b','c'),
  '#default_value' => array('a'),
  '#title' => t('The average vote is more than'),
);
```

I'm expecting *a* to be checked, but this doesn't happen. I'm using the Better Exposed Filters module, but I doubt that would make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Simplistically, the issue is that the default value uses the array key, not the array value.  So, there are two ways you can change this to make it work.

One:

```
$form['average'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => array('a' => 'a','b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c'),
  '#default_value' => array('a'),
  '#title' => t('The average vote is more than'),
);
```

or

```
$form['average'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => array('a','b','c'),
  '#default_value' => array(0),
  '#title' => t('The average vote is more than'),
);
```

Comment: I just copy/pasted the above into a form I had here and both worked so not sure what else is involved on your system that is making this not work.  The api docs clearly show this to be the correct case.  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#checkboxes shows it in the example.  The D7 version though https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#checkboxes, does say `the #options array cannot have a 0 key, as it would not be possible to discern checked and unchecked states` so definitely shy away from my second example.

Comment: the only other obvious thing to check is to make sure that since you are doing an alter that it is actually being called and the right element is actually being altered.  a drupal_set_message() or its equivalent might be helpful in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. Try this :

Here, I am altering a form, it can be a new form as well.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
    $options = array();
    $options = array('a','b','c');  
    $form['chekbox_check_issue'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#options' => $options,
      '#default_value' => array(0), /* Set the key values of the options array you want to be checked*/
      '#title' => t('The average vote is more than'),
    );
  } 
}
```

Hope it helps